# Graph isomorphism for twin free graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose you are given two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ and are promised that both are twin free. Is the problem of determining if they are isomorphic graph isomorphism hard? I am curious for the cases of simple as well as non-simple directed graphs.

Comment: What is "twin free"?

Comment: @joro I assume *twins* are pairs of vertices with exactly the same neighbours.  And *twin free* means no two vertices are twins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twins are easy to detect. Equivalence classes of twins can be replaced by single vertices with colours (or attached gadgets if you don't like colours) that encode the multiplicity.  So the general case is no harder than the twin-free case.